# AJAX completa a URL a partir de onde foi chamado

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou começando a usar AJAX agora, então não sei se isso que está acontecendo é o normal dele. Eu fiz este código para fazer uma busca de CPF no banco de dados

```
$('#btn_buscar_cpf_responsavel').on('click', function(){
        var cpf = $('#aluno_responsavel_cpf').val();
        if (cpf == '') {
            alert('Informe um CPF');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'cpf' : cpf},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                        alert('Responsável não cadastrado');
                        $('#responsavel_novo').val(1);
                    } else {
                        $('#aluno_responsavel_nome').val(data[0].responsavel_nome);
                        var rg_uf = data[0].responsavel_rg + '/' + data[0].responsavel_rg_uf;
                        $('#aluno_responsavel_rg').val(rg_uf);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro' + Error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

E quero que ele mande o POST para essa URL, porém ele está completando a URL de onde ele foi chamado mais essa que passei no cógido, e fica o seguinte:

> http://192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/alunos/192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf

Tem alguma forma para que ele não comece a URL com `http://192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/alunos`?

Comment: Vai mandar pro que vc colocou na opção `url`, ou seja: `url: '192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf'`

Comment: Então, ele está mandando para http://192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/alunos/ (onde o AJAX foi chamado) + o que coloquei na opçao url: 192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf

Comment: coloca `http://` na `url` já que vc está informando o caminho absoluto. Assim: `url: 'http://192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf'`

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que está informando o caminho absoluto na opção `url` do Ajax, adicione o protocolo `http://`:

```
url: 'http://192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf'
```

Se não o Ajax vai entender que se trata de um caminho à partir de onde ele está sendo chamado, ou seja, que `192.168.0.26/cvt-sergipetec/utils/verify_responsavel_cpf` é uma subpasta.